# Bundle PDF+LaTeX source in OS X and open with Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, latex, preview

There must be a solution to the following problem and I think it could be interesting to a lot of people: I would like to create a new file type ".pdflatex", a document bundle, which contains a LaTeX source file and its compiled PDF such that when I double click on this file the PDF is opened in Preview (or my favorite PDF viewer). Moreover, I would like that programs like DevonThink understand this and correctly preview/show the PDF file.

I want this to comfortably deal with PDF files and their LaTeX source. This should be possible in OS X but I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but no clue how...

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want to distribute latex source code and compile it every time you try to open it? Because Latex is not HTML, you can't modify it on the fly. It's more like a programming language, there is a lot of stuff going on behind the scenes during compilation. Some stuff has to be compiled more than once to look properly. You can, however, make a simple script, that compiles '.pdflatex' file and opens it in your favourite viewer, and associate it with your extension. But modifying a pdf Word-style with Latex behind the scenes? Awesome idea, but I don't think so.

Comment: And if you just want to make one file out of latex and it's pdf version... well you can put it in .zip, and again, write a script that unpacks pdf file to some temporary location, opens it and deletes it when you close your viewer.

Comment: No! Perhaps I wasn't too precise. Just imagine having a directory "foo" containing you LaTeX file and your compiled PDF. I would now like to rename this directory to "foo.pdflatex" making it into an OS X bundle (so pdflatex is a special extension describing a document bundle). Now, when I double click in the finder on "foo.pdflatex" Preview opens and displays the PDF file contained in "foo.pdflatex". In this way I don't see the LaTeX source and additional stuff if I don't want to!

Comment: And really I would also like that programs understand this file type and correctly display the bundled PDF. So zipping is definitely _not_ a solution to this problem!

Answer (score 1):

I think the .zip (or other compressed directory format) is the answer here. You want to write a script that compiles your pdf and then stuffs your .tex and .pdf into that directory and renames it to something like "file.pdflatex". I would have it consistently name the .tex and .pdf the same thing, like "source.tex" and "output.pdf".

Then you just need to write a script (in whatever language) that extracts the pdf and opens it, which you can call from the command line or associate with the ".pdflatex" file extension.

Here's an example in R (which you can treat as pseuodo-code for any language):

```
f <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
untar(f, file='output.pdf')
browseURL('output.pdf')
# optionally you could delete the extracted pdf after you open it:
unlink('output.pdf')
```

Then you can just call this script from the command line like:

```
> pdflatexextract.R file.pdflatex
```

That's simply as an example. This is really not a hard problem at all.

Comment: So, if I add this to, say Papers, DevonThink or any other program handling PDF files, does it understand this and display the PDF? I think not.